# Error JBDC Sql Server

Tags: sql-server, jdbc

I'm with a problem to establish a JDBC connection to SQL Server 2008.
The following error message is displayed:

"Esse driver não está configurado para autenticação integrada."

What can be?

Tks!

Comment: What is your connection string? The error message itself says: _"This driver is not configured for integrated authentication."_ Which either means you didn't provide a user name and password, but also didn't specify `integratedSecurity=true` in the connection properties, or you did specify `integratedSecurity=true`, but the driver can't load the necessary .dll or .so (although I believe that would give a different error).

Answer (score 0):

This means that you do not have the correct SQL Server 2008 JDBC libraries either configured or added to your classpath (or ld_library path).  You'll need to install these:

```
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/aa937724.aspx
```